# Why do i have a small rectangle on the bottom right of my mouse cursor

Tags: 13.10, mouse, cursor

I am a complete linux noob. I have built a new computer and am really interested in linux and as such have installed ubuntu 13.10 on it to play around with and learn. My new computer is an Asrock extreme 6+ with the AMD A10 7850k Kaveri processor and 8GB of corsair vengeance pro 1866 RAM. My cursor has a small rectangle affixed to it that follows it around. Whilst i can live with this i was just wondering if anyone has encountered this issue and possibly resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

this problem of graphic card upgrade to latest ubuntu version then install ati drivers

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo shutdown -r
$ update-manager –d
```

then u have te reset unity

```
$ setsid unity
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme  
choose one of them
$ sudo apt-get update
```

now install the ati driver

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install fglrx gksu
$ sudo amdconfig --initial && sudo shutdown -r
```

after the reboot u can run the driver buy ALT + F2
copy & past this

```
gksu amdcccle
```